# $f,g$ continuous and periodic functions with 1, Prove: periodic $\widehat {f*g}(n)=\hat f(n)\cdot \hat g(n)$

Tags: calculus

I'd like to prove that Fourier coefficient of two continuous and periodic functions, with a period of $1$, the following equality holds:

$$\widehat {f*g}(n)=\hat f(n)\cdot \hat g(n)$$

( $\hat x(n)$- Fourier coefficient of $x$,  and  $y*z$- Convolution of $y$ and $z$)

If I knew that $f, g$ are continually  differentiable I could have used the fact that Fourier series $f,g$ converge to the actual functions, and I could use it to prove the claim. How can I prove it with these conditions and without using the order of the integrals, cause I am able to prove with that, but I am not allowed to.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Write down the definition for the $n$th Fourier coefficient for $f*g$; then switch the order of integration. The inner integral can be seen to be the Fourier coefficient of $g$, then the outer integral gives the Fourier coefficient of $f$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/96913/15941 ?

Comment: as I wrote down I'm searching for a solution which does not involve the switching the order of integration,Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$\eqalign{
(\widehat{f\star g  })(n)
&={1\over T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} (f\star g)(t) e^{-in\omega t}\,dt\cr
&={1\over T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} f(u)g(t-u)\,du \ e^{-in\omega  t}\,dt \cr
&={1\over T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} f(u)g(t-u) \ e^{-in\omega   t} \,dt\,\,du \cr
&={1\over T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}\Bigl[ \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} g(t-u)  e^{-in\omega   (t-u)}\,dt \Bigr] e^{-in\omega   u}f(u)   \,du \cr
&=T\cdot
{1\over T}
\Bigl[ \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} g(t-u)  e^{-in\omega   (t-u)}\,dt \Bigr] {1\over T}
\Bigl[\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}e^{-in\omega   u}f(u)   \,du \Bigr]\cr
&=T\cdot\hat f(n)\hat g(n).
}
$$

Comment: What does $T$ stands for? I mean why did you chose to integrate between $ -T / 2 $ to $ T / 2 $?

Comment: @Josef Sorry, the period of the function.

Comment: So basically you showed that  it works for every $T$?

Comment: @Josef Yes but notice the factor of $T$ at the end...

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the convolution suppose to yield a $1/T$ as well according to the formula, no?

Comment: @Jozef Sorry, I should have used the definition $f\star g={1\over t}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} f(u)g(t-u)\,du$.  This would introduce another factor of ${1\over T}$ in the second step. And the result would be $(\widehat{f\star g})(n) =\hat f(n)\hat g(n)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Could you please comment on why switching the order of integration is allowed here?