# Is it true that the Fourier coefficient of convolution is the product of the coefficients?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

what I mean by the title is the following: if we define the convolution between two $2\pi$-periodic, $C^1$ functions as $f*g(x) = (2\pi)^{-1}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x-y)g(y)dy$, is it true that the Fourier coefficients of $f*g(x)$ equal $\hat{f}(n)\hat{g}(n)$ where $\hat{f}(n),\hat{g}(n)$ are the Fourier coefficients of $f,g$ respectively?

I think I have a correct proof of this, but I am just unsure, but the result seems so beautiful, so I wanted to hear your expert opinions. Please do not post the proof of this...

Thanks

Comment: if you don't want a proof, why you don't post your proof? (and add the tag proof-verfication)

Comment: @rlartiga Since I am only asking whether or not the result of my (secret) proof is correct, I did not feel that I need to post my proof.

Comment: A ok I was going to post you the convolution theorem of wiki as Oliver did. Good luck then

Comment: Why do need $C^{1}$ functions ? Its even true for $L^{1}$ functions; and $C^{1}(\mathbb T) \subset L^{1}(\mathbb T).$

Comment: @Divyang Bhimani True, but the question I faced did not expect that much from us :)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97328/f-g-continuous-and-periodic-functions-with-1-prove-periodic-widehat-fg

Answer (score 4):

Given the assumed smoothness of $f$ and $g$ this is a simple exercise about double integrals. I write $\int_T$ for the integral over a full period. Then
$$\widehat{f*g}(n)={1\over2\pi}\int_T f*g(x)\>e^{-inx}\>dx={1\over4\pi^2}\int_T\left(\int_Tf(x-y)g(y)\>dy\right)e^{-inx}\ dx\ .$$
Interchanging the order of integration gives
$$\widehat{f*g}(n)={1\over4\pi^2}\int_T g(y) \left(\int_Tf(x-y)\>e^{-inx}\> dx\right)\,dy\ .$$
In the inner integral we substitute $x:=y+t$ $(t\in T)$ and obtain
$$\widehat{f*g}(n)={1\over4\pi^2}\int_T g(y) \left(\int_Tf(t)\>e^{-in(y+t)}\> dt\right)\,dy={1\over4\pi^2}\int_T g(y) e^{-iny}\left(\int_Tf(t)\>e^{-int}\> dt\right)\,dy\ .$$
On the right hand side the inner integral is independent of $y$ and essentially $=\hat f(n)$. We therefore can write
$$\widehat{f*g}(n)=\hat f(n)\>{1\over2\pi}\int_T g(y) e^{-iny}\>dy=\hat f(n)\cdot\hat g(n)\ .$$

Comment: Should not you check that the integral over a full period does not depend on the choice of period? Is there an elegant, clean, nice, neat, short proof of this?

Comment: @WillM.: I'm sure it has been checked in the course that $f*g$ is periodic with period $T$. We all know that we can take any interval of length $T$ to compute the Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Why can one change the order of integration?

Comment: @mavavilj: Since $f$ and $g$ have been assumed $C^1$ this is a simple application of Fubini's theorem, whether under Riemann or under Lebesgue integration.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that Fourier coefficient of convolution of two functions is the product of Fourier coefficients of the individual functions. This is called convolution theorem in Fourier theory . You may be interested to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I feel more confident now :).

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Minor point, but the reference is about the Fourier transform, the question is about Fourier series.

Comment: Here is the reference for Fourier Series:   https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Fourier_series

Comment: The article linked to is for Fourier transforms of convolutions -- is the result still true for Fourier coefficients, rather than the Fourier transform?