# Show that $(Ax)(t) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} | t - s | x(s) ds$ is compact, self adjoint and find its norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

The question is as follows:

Show that $(Ax)(t) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} | t - s | x(s) ds$ for $A : L_2[-\pi , \pi ] \to L_2[-\pi , \pi ] $, is compact, self adjoint and find its norm.

$\textbf{Some efort:}$

We know that for operator $(Ax)(t) = \int_{a}^{b} k(t , s) x(s) ds$ we have that $(A^*x)(t) = \int_{a}^{b} \bar{k(s , t)} x(s) ds$ is its adjoint operator. Here we have $ k(t , s) = | t - s | = | s - t | = \bar{k(s , t)}$. So it is self adjoint.

For to show it is compact, we show that it is Hilbert–Schmidt integral operator, meaning that $\left( \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \mid \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  t - s  ds \mid^2 dt \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} < + \infty.$

We have \begin{align}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \mid \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  |t - s | ds  \mid^2 dt &\le  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  |t - s |^2 ds  dt 
\\&= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  \left( \int_{-\pi}^{t}  (t - s )^2 ds + \int_{t}^{\pi}  ( s - t )^2 ds \right)  dt \\& = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left( -\frac{(t+s)^3}{3} \mid_{-\pi}^{t} + \frac{(s-t)^3}{3} \mid_{t}^{\pi} \right) dt \\& = 0 \end{align}

So it is Hilbert–Schmidt integral operator and so is compact.

But I do not know how to find its spectrum.

Can you please let me know if my calculation is correct so far and can you please let me know what will be its spectrum?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to compute the norm or the full spectrum?

Comment: In any case, [Fourier Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/757259/8157) may be very helpful.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks! First I need to know if my calculation is wrong or right. And then I need to know its spectrum. (I will appreciate if you also let me know its norm). Thanks again!

Comment: Since $0\leq |t-s|^2\not\equiv 0$ you can get $\int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi|t-s|^2~ds~dt=0$... Consider $|t-s|^2=(t-s)^2$ and you get $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi|t-s|^2~ds~dt = \int_{-\pi}^\pi 2\pi t^2+\frac23\pi^3~dt = \frac83\pi^4.$$

Comment: @MundronSchmidt Thanks! But I couldn't get your point? Do you know how can we find its spectrum?

Comment: To solve $ Au = \lambda u $ try $ \phi_n = e^{int} $ This is suggested by the corresponding differential equation. Then get $ e^{int}  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |v| e^{-inv} dv $. Can regard functions extended by periodicity outside  $ [-\pi , \pi] $. This last integral is the $ nth $ eigenvalue, which you evaluate. It should be real.

Comment: @user510716 My point is just that you have a mistake in your computations. The others may help you to answer your question, I can't.